# Date Range to select data from View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server

I have created a view which is containing different joins
and data looks like

v_Test

```
Id           Date          Salary

A1           1-10-2020      700
A2           2-04-2020      1200
A3           3-07-2021      600
A4           4-07-2021      400
```

I am trying to get output below whose salary is less than 1000 and date range for month July

```
Id           Date          Salary

A3           3-07-2021      600
A4           4-07-2021      400
```

I am using following query

```
Select *
from V_test
where salary <= 1000
and Date between '01-07-2021' and '4-07-2021'
```

My query is not working

Comment: Can you add your output please?

Comment: its giving me full list of records

Comment: @Salman81 Can you add description about datatype for each column ? Because format `Date` column is strange because in `v_Test` looks different than you use in the query.

Comment: You are right @Cesc, same for salary, if salary is integer and considering some issue with Date columns then it should return 3 results, not all, Salman, please confirm datatype

Comment: use date format `YYYYMMDD` and your query should be fine

Comment: Salary is an additional Column which is already set in a view. Salary is containing a value after calculation(E.g Salary = columnA+columnB) and Date has type smalldatetime.

Comment: it works when salary < =1000 and Date = '3-07-2021 ' but not picking up range such as date = '1-07-2021' and '31-07-2021'

Comment: @Salman81  Try `salary < =1000 and Date = '1-07-2021 '` and `salary < =1000 and Date = '01-07-2021 '`  if one of them works

Comment: Show the expression you use for your computed `Date` column. There are hints that it is a string and not any temporal datatype.

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be clear after your comment. You swap months and days. I am adding a sample.

For example:

```
Select *
from t
where salary <= 1000
and datum between '7-01-2020' and '7-31-2020'
```

[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5e509d7ee1bdb62ab7fa69acc7c36c9b)